# phoenix: Check unique constraint for a combination of fields

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a db table similar to following:

```
UID QID Attempt score
 1   1    1       4
 1   2    1       3
 1   1    2       5
 1   2    2       5
 2   1    1       2
 2   2    1       3
```

When inserting a new value, I want to make sure that a record doesn't already exist for a combination of UID, QID and Attempt.

How can I acheive this in Phoenix?
I am working on my first project in Phoenix, so don't know much.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One should not achieve this in _Phoenix_. Check the uniqueness of records in the database is indeed the duty of the database. Create a unique constraint on these three fields directly in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your migration you should define a unique index. Here's an example:

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateFoos do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:foos) do # note that you also get an id column as the primary key, but you can disable it with primary_key: false
      add :uid, :integer
      add :qid, :integer
      add :attempt, :integer
      add :score, :integer

      timestamps()
    end

    # tell your db that these columns should be unique
    create unique_index(:foos, [:uid, :qid, :attempt], name: :my_index)
  end
end
```

And in your schema, if you have one:

```
defmodule App.Foo do
  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "foos" do
    field :uid, :integer
    field :qid, :integer
    field :attempt, :integer
    field :score, :integer

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(foo, attrs) do
    foo
    |> cast(attrs, [:uid, :qid, :attempt, :score])
    |> validate_required([:uid, :qid, :attempt, :score])
    |> unique_constraint(:my_constraint, name: :my_index) # tell ecto that there's a unique constraint
  end
end
```